# Removing the bold and italics in the bibtex output

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to format my references for my thesis (I'm supposed to use the [AMS style format](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf)). I was requested to remove any bold and italics from my references. I'm using [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/). My thesis.bib file looks like this

```
    @article {MR1456898,
    AUTHOR = {Bay, Karlheinz and Lay, Wolfgang and Akopyan, Alexey},
     TITLE = {Avoided crossings of the quartic oscillator},
   JOURNAL = {J. Phys. A},
  FJOURNAL = {Journal of Physics. A. Mathematical and General},
    VOLUME = {30},
      YEAR = {1997},
    NUMBER = {9},
     PAGES = {3057--3067},
      ISSN = {0305-4470},
   MRCLASS = {81Q05},
  MRNUMBER = {1456898},
MRREVIEWER = {Gabriel Alvarez},
       DOI = {10.1088/0305-4470/30/9/017},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/30/9/017},
}

@book {MR1186643,
    AUTHOR = {Berezin, F. A. and Shubin, M. A.},
     TITLE = {The {S}chr\"{o}dinger equation},
    SERIES = {Mathematics and its Applications (Soviet Series)},
    VOLUME = {66},
      NOTE = {Translated from the 1983 Russian edition by Yu. Rajabov, D. A.
              Le\u{\i}tes and N. A. Sakharova and revised by Shubin,
              with contributions by G. L. Litvinov and Le\u{\i}tes},
 PUBLISHER = {Kluwer Academic Publishers Group, Dordrecht},
      YEAR = {1991},
     PAGES = {xviii+555},
      ISBN = {0-7923-1218-X},
   MRCLASS = {81-01 (35J10 35P05 46N50 47F05 47N50)},
  MRNUMBER = {1186643},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-94-011-3154-4},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-3154-4},
}
```

and the only latex command I use is

```
\bibliography{thesis}
```

The output appears as follows:

[image]

How can I remove both the italics and bold from the output?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In your file there should be a `\bibliographystyle` command.  What does it specify?  (The AMS styles automatically apply italic to some titles, and bold to journal volume numbers, so your instructions are contradictory.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not sure how to see what \bibliographystyle specifies. As I said I used overleaf in hopes of making this easier without having to download and  configure various libraries. Would you care to enlighten me where I can find and  modify this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a total hack, but you could simply redefine `\emph` and `\textbf` to do nothing just before `\bibliography{thesis}`. e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article {MR1456898,
    AUTHOR = {Bay, Karlheinz and Lay, Wolfgang and Akopyan, Alexey},
     TITLE = {Avoided crossings of the quartic oscillator},
   JOURNAL = {J. Phys. A},
  FJOURNAL = {Journal of Physics. A. Mathematical and General},
    VOLUME = {30},
      YEAR = {1997},
    NUMBER = {9},
     PAGES = {3057--3067},
      ISSN = {0305-4470},
   MRCLASS = {81Q05},
  MRNUMBER = {1456898},
MRREVIEWER = {Gabriel Alvarez},
       DOI = {10.1088/0305-4470/30/9/017},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/30/9/017},
}
@book {MR1186643,
    AUTHOR = {Berezin, F. A. and Shubin, M. A.},
     TITLE = {The {S}chr\"{o}dinger equation},
    SERIES = {Mathematics and its Applications (Soviet Series)},
    VOLUME = {66},
      NOTE = {Translated from the 1983 Russian edition by Yu. Rajabov, D. A.
              Le\u{\i}tes and N. A. Sakharova and revised by Shubin,
              with contributions by G. L. Litvinov and Le\u{\i}tes},
 PUBLISHER = {Kluwer Academic Publishers Group, Dordrecht},
      YEAR = {1991},
     PAGES = {xviii+555},
      ISBN = {0-7923-1218-X},
   MRCLASS = {81-01 (35J10 35P05 46N50 47F05 47N50)},
  MRNUMBER = {1186643},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-94-011-3154-4},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-3154-4},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begingroup
\let\emph\relax
\let\textbf\relax
\bibliography{\jobname}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]